# Carregar variáveis em php externo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou com uma página que preciso abrir vários modais, para não comprometer no carregamento da página decidi chamar os modais apenas quando o usuário o requisitasse. Fiz a seguinte função AJAX:

```
function loadModal(modalPage, modalBox){
$.ajax({
    url: "/modals/" + modalPage,
    success: function(data){
        $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html(data);
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html("<img src='/images/loading.gif'> Carregando...");
    },
    error: function(){
        $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html("Ocorreu uma erro!");
    }
});
}
```

Até ai tudo bem, consigo chamar com essa função qualquer página, mas o problema é que existem variáveis *php* que precisam ser consideradas, como `user_id` (que vem de um GET), depois de pego esse `id` faço vários tratamentos como buscar o usuário, traduzir umas datas, chamar mais umas tabelas relacionadas ao usuário. Isso na página principal, mas preciso que essas informações passem também para o modal de forma eficiente. Eu já pensei em passar o `user_id` por método GET no AJAX, e copiar todo aquele tratamento que faço na página principal. Como fazer o modal ler as variáveis sem precisar fazer isso? Ou eu preciso fazer isso? Do jeito que eu fiz, é o mais recomendado?

Comment: Você consegue retornar um Json com as informações do php para onde o ajax foi codificado? Acredito que dê para montar um Json com tudo o que você precisa e no retorno podem ser pegos os valores que você precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem, mas se essas variáveis PHP estão definidas ($_GET) na página que você chama o modal, bastaria fazer algo do tipo.

```js
<?php 

$data = array('user_id' => $_GET['user_id']); 

?>

function loadModal(modalPage, modalBox) {
  
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
  
  $.ajax({
    url: "/modals/" + modalPage,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html(data);
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html("<img src='/images/loading.gif'> Carregando...");
    },
    error: function() {
      $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html("Ocorreu uma erro!");
    }
  });
}
```